# pstricks: Color area under graph: what is dup?

Tags: graphics, pstricks, graphs, postscript

For coloring an area under a graph, there exist multiple approaches with pstricks.

I found a solution that was never mentioned on stack-exchange, but seems to be really simple:

```
\psplot[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue]{0.01}{5}{x log}
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linestyle=none]{%
  \psline(3,0)(!3 dup log)
  \psplot{3}{4}{x log}
  \psline(!4 dup log)(4,0)}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-.5,-2)(5,1)
```

However, I do not know how to adapt this example to e.g. `x^2` because I do not understand what `dup` does. Can anybody explain it?

Comment: `dup` means that the top stack entry is duplicated. See e.g. http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/Flat/stack-ref.html#PSdup

Comment: E.g., `(!3 dup log)` evaluates to the coordinate (3,log(3)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the algebraic notation instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(6,2)
\psplot[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue,algebraic]{0.01}{5}{log(x)}
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linestyle=none]{%
    \psline(3,0)(*3 {log(3)})
    \psplot[algebraic]{3}{4}{log(x)}
    \psline(*4 {log(4)})(4,0)}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-.5,-2)(5,1)   
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to color the area between two graphs?

Comment: sure: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/FunctionExamples#shadingbetween